# MYSQL Incorrect DOUBLE value Python 3

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

I am having an issue getting my UPDATE Query to work. I am using python 3.7 and building a gui using tkinter. I have an entry box that a user can select an Item by ID number, that auto-populates the following entry boxes and the user can then modify the entries. My error occurs when it comes time to save the changes. I have a button that calls a function save when clicked. see below

```
def save():
    conn = mysql.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="XXXX",
        passwd="XXXX",
        database="inventory")

    c = conn.cursor()

    a0 = selectent.get()

    a1 = item.get()
    a2 = asset_tag.get()
    a3 = amount.get()
    a4 = notes.get()

    c.execute(""" UPDATE items SET
        item = 'a1',
        asset_tag = 'a2',
        amount = 'a3',
        notes = 'a4'

        WHERE id = 'a0' """)
        
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

I am self-teaching myself mySQL, and from what I have read about this error it appears that the error occurs when trying to compare a number and string in a WHERE clause. This makes sense since my traceback takes me to that line in my code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mbrow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\mbrow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Inventory3\editmodule.py", line 61, in save
    WHERE id = 'a0' """)
  File "C:\Users\mbrow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 266, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  File "C:\Users\mbrow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 475, in cmd_query
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a0'
```

Can someone explain this to me so I better understand what is going on?

*I know amount is spelled wrong.*

Comment: What is the structure of your database table?

Comment: You are passing literal strings to the database. Do research on _parameterized queries_.

Comment: can you exlain why you are not using prepared statements instead of using sti8rngs in your quey

Comment: Thank you for the tip Bryan, I definitely need to do more research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameterized query and prepared statement

```
c.execute(""" UPDATE items SET
    item = %s,
    asset_tag = %s,
    amount = %s,
    notes = %s

    WHERE id = %s """,(a1,a2,a3,a4,a0))
```

Comment: Thank you this worked splendidly. As Bryan mentioned above, I need to do more studying on parameterized queries.